# how to get URL date(year/month/day) in WordPress in case DAY and Name is selected in permalinks settings

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

I have a wordpress page where it's URL is `http://localhost/MyWebsite/news/2018/10/` and I want to get the date from this URL 
in case I choose `plain` option in `settings > permalinks` it give this kind of url `http://localhost/stormhounds/?p=123&m=201811` so I can access this date through `get_query_var('m')` function but since I chose `Day and name` in `settings > permalinks` I can't use this funtion to get the date. *So any other way to get that date*

Comment: This date is created from the post info - So you can just take the date from the post meta instead -> `get_the_date($post_id)` - where `post_id` defaults to current post..

Comment: to only get the month - you would go `get_the_date('m', $post_id)` - read more here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/

Comment: So it gives the date for the post which type of the post is page?

Comment: Works on pages as well - Just `get_the_date(get_the_ID());` will give you the date of whatever you are currently on.